# How to use style="text-align:center;" on the ordinary text?

Tags: html

For now I have used `<h1></h1>`
What to do if I want to center the text without using the header?

Answer (score 1):

```css
h1{
    text-align: center;
}
p{
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<h1>My Text<h1/>
<p>some other text</p>
```

You should start using css to code everything about the html properties, not inside the html code

Answer (score 1):

Text -- regular paragraphs of text -- should be wrapped in paragraph tags (`<p></p>`). You can then center all p tags (or just the one you're targetting).

```css
p {
  text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<h1>I am a heading</h1>

<p>I am regular text</p>
```

Alternatively, if you want to center *everything*, you can style the `<body>` tag.

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>I am a header</h1>
<h2>I am a subheader</h2>

I am unwrapped text.

<p>I am text in a paragraph tag.</p>
```

Note that putting the style on the body will center *everything*.

(Some browsers will implicitly wrap your regular text in `<p>` tags if you don't, but it's much better practice for you to do it yourself.)